# How to sign and verify string using ssh key using java

Tags: java, ssh, rsa, private-key, public-key

I know this issue may be duplicated somewhere else, but i wasted a lot of time to fix this issue.

I need to use third party API and as per their documentation i have to generate private/public key using the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, send to them the public key and for every request i must sign the request body using my private key

i found many code sample to read private/public key of formats like `pem` or `der`, but not the format generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

my private key now is

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,07E3CD04C0D5E7AEC5BFB3660C389A79
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

my public key

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDZ98gmTkAoteabP96SmMDWAsPYIj5tV4iovMC9IEeWtiV1DbOIYVYpp27YM2DezoEuBwbccG9+A2wygyYKAVJurfmQTTL4h2WxJ5UIRJtwKrc2UKZNA6amUfIEcQHt0qJeTk6t5Havte2eTU3P6p15J7sHonLdeVBqybjeUMTOc8g41uUtTtmgTSp3BORkY/qwYzC7bICWZuuoklathRgj0CATkfkz25kggV/cNiWo8Ngr2mM8qB3EZxidF6FYwGROYRFq9jPfn1K3EvgOWWsPeHwd/bJn109sTqaLY5TsKuatxZAE+3CHNoQsEGaAVtEz505Oa8IRJYp9LERuBHx1 melad@pcwrk005.bovc.dk
```

how to read these files using java and `sign,verify` strings using them

Comment: `ssh-keygen -t rsa` doesn't generate private keys that look like that, you'd have to add an option like `-m PEM`.